# RSS feed image format broken

Tags: html, rss, feed

We are providing a RSS feed for our blog. A couple of customers are complaining about broken image formatting. I have tried it using "Vienna RSS reader" and it is indeed broken. The images seem weirdly warped. Apart from that everything kind of seems to work.

It seems my company is always sending the whole article via RSS. I am not sure this is the right way. Is it not smarter to send a small message like in twitter via RSS accompanied by a link?

Please give me your opinion on the matter. Does it seems weird to send pictures via RSS feed at all?

Edit 1: I am wondering if i should strive to fix the images, or rather change our whole concept of sending the complete article into sending a link only.

Edit 2: Is there a golden standard of RSS that i should follow? How is RSS meant to work?

Edit 3: Back on topic then: How can i fix my images? How should they be formatted? In my RSS reader every image seems to have the same ratio.

Comment: "Please give me your opinion on the matter" — Your question is off-topic.

Comment: see edit for clarification

Comment: The edit doesn't help. You're still asking for opinions.

Comment: Why does it not help? I am asking if there is a "golden standard". I am asking how it "should" be done.

Comment: You aren't asking that (or weren't before that last comment), and there isn't anyway, it is a matter of opinion.

Comment: "How can i fix my images?" — We can't tell what is wrong with the code without seeing the code.